# Drupal 7 - access to page content in template.php

Tags: 7, theming

In Drupal 7 I'm trying to access the body field of a page from template.php. I want to find a keyword in the text and then send subsequent text to a separate variable so that I can format it in page.tpl.php

I can access the node using 
    *$vars['node']*
but can't find a way of accessing the content part of the node.

I can access the content in page.tpl.php using:
    *$node->body[$node->language][0]['value']*
but cant use the same or similar syntax in template.php

Answer (score 1):

In [`page.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/7) the content of the ***page*** is available in `$page['content']`. It seems that your are mixing two different concepts here: *pages*, any page on the site (including administration page, taxonomy terms page, and other not directly editable pages) and [*nodes*](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/node), editable content. This can be rather confusing as a default Drupal installation provides a *page* content type. So you end up with *page nodes*, which are nodes of a the page content type.

The layout of the content of a page displaying a node, is handled in the [`node.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php) template. In this template, the body of the displayed node is available in `$content['body']`.

If you really need to access a field (handled using the Field API) of the node object (`$node`) from the page preprocess function in your template.php, you can use:

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $node =& $variables['node'];
    $value = field_get_items('node', $node, 'FIELDNAME);
}
```